# Missing file for driver patch (Atheros AR9485)

Tags: 13.04, drivers, kernel, atheros, patch

First, it should be known that I have never applied a patch before.  It's high time I learned, and lord knows no one else is going to do it for me.  Any info that could help me advance the ball would be most appreciated.

Like many Linux users, I have experienced very weak signals with my Atheros AR9845 adapter.  After trying many of the fixes I found (to no avail), a helpful participant in the IRC #ubuntu room pointed me to this [patch](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/2718041/).

I'd like to apply said patch, but I can't find the appropriate files.  I see the folder where they should be (/lib/modules/3.9.0-030900-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k), but the files mentioned in the patch do not exist.

After looking through the bug discussion, it appears that the patch should be applied on top of 3.10-rc6 (I think).  Does this mean I have to upgrade from Raring Ringtail 3.9 to Saucy Salamander 3.9 and then update to 3.10-rc6?

Do I need to backport wireless drivers into my current kernel version?  If so, a point in the right direction for an example of doing this with later kernel versions would be most appreciated.  I have seen a number of examples for pre-3.7 kernels, but it looks like the method of sharing these backports has changed.  To be honest, I am a bit at a loss for how to proceed with the new site at this point.

I am currently using an ASUS Q550LF, and I am happy to edit with more info if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to install the new driver.
all the instructions are here : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/971809/comments/63

Comment: your link may answer the question exactly but include part of the answer, thank you.

Comment: BIG TIME!!!  Much appreciated starsseed, it's all gravy now.  Note that this driver does work for Ubuntu 13.04 (though I think it was developed for 13.10)

Comment: I'd upvote you if I could, but I am too new to the forum.